# What is the best practice for handling abandoned packages required by the drupal core?

Tags: updating, composer

When I run `composer update` on a Drupal 9 website, I get this warning:

> Package doctrine/reflection is abandoned, you should avoid using it. Use roave/better-reflection instead.

A similar question has alreday been asked, answered and accepted on [StackOverflow](https://stackoverflow.com/q/59537660/1837734).

To summarise the accepted answer:

- edit your `composer.json` and replace the abandoned package with the recommended replacement
- then run `composer update` again

I seriously doubt that manually altering `composer.json` is the best practice, but that is moot, because it does not apply in the case of "doctrine/reflection". When looking into my `composer.json`, there is no mention of it, so there is nothing to edit.

So I am checking *why* it is required:

```
$ composer why doctrine/reflection
doctrine/common          2.13.3  requires  doctrine/reflection (^1.0)   
doctrine/persistence     1.3.8   requires  doctrine/reflection (^1.2)   
drupal/core              9.1.7   requires  doctrine/reflection (^1.1)   
drupal/core-recommended  9.1.7   requires  doctrine/reflection (1.2.2)
```

So this abandoned package is required by `drupal/core` (and others).

In an upvoted commnent, user Kay V writes:

> People needing more generic composer usage instructions should consider $ composer remove {{old package}} and then $ composer require {{new package}}.

This doesn't work either, it produces the following messages:

> doctrine/reflection is not required in your composer.json and has not been removed [...]
> Removal failed, doctrine/reflection is still present, it may be required by another package. See `composer why doctrine/reflection`.

Two questions:

1. Why is the most recent version of `drupal/core` requiring an abandoned package (instead of its recommended replacement `roave/better-reflection`)?
2. What is the best practice for handling abandoned packages required by the drupal core?

Comment: The corresponding d.o. issue https://www.drupal.org/project/drupal/issues/3180351

Comment: @leymannx - Thanks for answering the first of my two questions.  The answer to my second one (what to do about it?) is probably: Nothing - just wait until the core issue is sorted out.

Comment: It's a good question, I mean +1. I thought you could maybe trick Composer into taking one package as another package or to somehow use recommended replacements easily. But I didn't found anything. What you always can do – much better than nothing – is to get involved in the issue and/or create some momentum elsewhere (Twitter, Slack etc.).

Comment: @leymannx - Yes, Drupal.org is a community and one I am aware that one *should* pay forward the incredible tremendous effort the community has put into the project by getting involved in issues. However, I am still trying to get my head wrapped round *composer*, and I'm afraid I don't have the enough courage to get involved in a core issue involving *composer*.

Answer (score 0):

This is not *really* an answer since you asked for 'best practice', but it does work. Considering

> The code from doctrine/reflection has been copied to drupal/components.
> The code from doctrine/reflection is no longer been used in core.

(#39 in the official thread https://www.drupal.org/project/drupal/issues/3180351), I would say that the package can just be ignored with composers `replace` top-level keyword:

```
"replace": {
    "doctrine/reflection": "*"
}
```

This only works since the package is not only abandoned, but completely unnecessary for Drupal to function, so we can safely skip the download.

There is a thread on the composer GitHub with an interesting solution proposal to add a new top-level keyword `suppress` that would behave more elegantly: https://github.com/composer/composer/issues/6133#issuecomment-1040176900